# What can I use to let me know how many times a file has been accessed in a month?

Tags: windows, python

I have a Windows 2016 server and is there a Free program or script that I can use/run to monitor a specific folder which will keep a tally/log on how many times the files in the folder have been accessed? 
For example, at the end of the month, check the log and it should tell me;

File1.txt was accessed 10 times
File2.txt was accessed 20 times

and so on. then I can reset the stats and start all over again for the next month? Also, if it can be a little more specific and I can actually tell the software what files I want it to monitor because I don't care about some of the other files that are in the folder but that feature is not very important but would be nice to have and would keep the log shorter.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That describes Nirsoft's [FileActivityWatch](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_activity_watch.html), a small, free tool that requires no installation. It can record all file activity, or just that for specific files or by specific processes.

[image: Nirsoft's FileActivityWatch]

In the view above, I created a text file and opened it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the suggestion. Looks like just what I need.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to ignore Process ID? like in your picture, the same file name is listed 3 times because it happened to grab a different Process ID while it was read so that means I would have to add up all the Read columns together instead of just keeping it tidy and if it's the same file name then keep it on the same row while it's tallying the Reads/Writes.

Comment: Although it's possible to *not* display all columns identifying processes, the program still displays item on separate line by the (hidden) process. You could export the HTML report, though, and use an editor to help count by column.